# Lua: how to load a large CSV file into a table and acess it

Tags: file, csv, lua, load

I'm new at Lua and I can't load a csv file that looks like this :

```
22.74,22.99,23.47,24.44,26.39,30.27,38.05,53.6,84.7,146.9,271.3,520.1,1017.7,2012.89,4003.28,7984.06,15945.63,31868.75,63715.01,127407.52,254792.53
```

there are 21 values separated by a comma with no space in the line. I have hundreds of lines. and hundreds of files. 
I need to load these lines in a table in Lua and be able to access with simple coordinates (i, j). I would like to call each number cs1, cs2, cs3... cs21 and each line by a number.

I have looked at this function

```
    function readwaypoints(filename, numberofwaypoints)
  local file = io.open(filename)
  local waypoints = {}
  for n = 1, numberofwaypoints do
    local x, y, z
    x = file:read('*n')
    y = file:read('*n')
    z = file:read('*n')
    waypoints[#waypoints+1] = {['x'] = x, ['y'] = y, ['z'] = z}
  end
  file:close()
  return waypoints
end
```

But it does not seem to work. Or I don't know how to access the data.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to my problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `*n` expects a number in the input and will skip whitespaces, but not commas. You will need to "eat" commas with `file:read(1)` or something similar.

```
function readwaypoints(filename, numberofwaypoints)
  local file = io.open(filename)
  local waypoints = {}
  for n = 1, numberofwaypoints do
    local x, y, z
    x = file:read('*n'); file:read(1) --<-- added
    y = file:read('*n'); file:read(1) --<-- added
    z = file:read('*n'); file:read(1) --<-- added
    waypoints[#waypoints+1] = {['x'] = x, ['y'] = y, ['z'] = z}
  end
  file:close()
  return waypoints
end

local waypoints = readwaypoints("waypoints.txt", 20)
print(waypoints[2].x == 24.44, waypoints[1].z == 23.47)
```

This prints `true true` for me. You can access these elements with `waypoints[<number of waypoints>].x` (or `y/z`).